# What files do I add from an APK to a GitHub Repository?

Tags: github, apk

If I wanted to add files from a decompiled APK to a GitHub repository, which files should I use? Do I need to convert the classes.dex file to a .jar then add it? Do I need to include all of the .xml files from the "res" directory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add any files... This answer depends on the purpose of the Github

Comment: The purpose of the GitHub is to allow multiple people to work on the app and make changes to things.

Comment: Sure. My point is that you can upload anything. And you can later commit modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK GitHub does not impose any restrictions on what kinds of files are included in uploaded `git` repositories. You're free to add whatever you want.

There is a filesize restriction though, look into [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for more detail if applicable to your use case. Also be careful that you are not uploading any sensitive information (private ssh keys, api keys, etc.) in public GitHub repositories. This can be facilitated via `.gitignore` files or even just moving the secrets outside of your local repository.

And - be nice to GitHub. I've seen countless of repositories where people carelessly upload heavy build artifacts and large, useless things like random compiled binaries and other similar junk.